# How can I use Firebase storage 'List All' method in Xamarin forms(CSharp)

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, storage

I have to show all the files and folders stored in cloud storage (now I am trying to use Firebase storage) into a list in my Xamarin forms application.
I am not able to use ListAll method of firebase in csharp. Neither I am getting any Download All method.

Please help me how can I list or download all the files to my app. Also suggest me which storage should i use to perform this functionality on Xamarin Forms. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking something for Dropbox, I have a link:

https://medium.com/crossplatform/xamarin-forms-dropbox-integration-e51d9ae0b350

Comment: I tried implementing the same using DropBox. and that worked. Thanks you for your help. :)